# converting from struct to float*

Tags: c++, matrix, struct, floating-point

I have a struct

```
typedef struct
{
    float   m[4][4];
} myMatrix;
```

because of some need of the program I need to convert this to float*

I do it something like

```
if(! g_Fvar16)
    g_Fvar16 = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 16);
memcpy(&g_Fvar16, &struct_var, sizeof(float)*16);
return g_Fvar16;
```

this is one simple function. Now, from where I call this function, program crashes on accessing these values. `g_Fvar16` is `float*`

`sizeof(struct_var)` is 64 and so is the amount of memory allocated.

Can't I simply treat the copied memory as float*? I thougt this would be the fastest..

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. --- First you need to understand what a pointer is and how one is converted to an array. Apart from that, you **can** absolutely copy the array.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g_fVer16` is already a pointer, so you have to write

```
memcpy(g_Fvar16, &struct_var, sizeof(float)*16);
```

instead of

```
memcpy(&g_Fvar16, &struct_var, sizeof(float)*16);
```

(note the first `&`)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
float *ptr = &(struct_var.m[0][0]);
```

for that "conversion".

You could possibly even avoid doing the copy, just pass the program the converted pointer (but this requires you handle the lifetime correctly, i.e. the `struct` instance should remain alive long enough for the function to use the data).

Comment: Just doing `float * ptr = &struct_var;` would also do it, as `m` is the **1st** member.

Comment: ya.. this is true if i want to use it as float*, but its argument to some other function, which accepts float*. Would this work in that case..?

Comment: @alk: That's a type error (you need to do a `cast` to avoid it... but why going messy if you can just pass the address of the correct element?)

Comment: @Adorn: yes, you can simply pass `&struct_var.m[0][0]` to the function directly; no conversion of any kind is needed. Of course you need to be sure to keep around the struct at least until the function is done with processing the values.